# Obtaining "AddOrReplace" functionality with a ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using a ConcurrentDictionary to create a simple Object cache.  I am trying to atomically add an item to the collection if the key does not exist, or replace the previous item if the key does already exist, i.e. "AddOrReplace".  There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this.  Can someone suggest how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can't you just use the indexer?

```
dictionary[key] = value;
```

See [Stephen Toub's blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/01/08/9945809.aspx):

> If you want to...
>   [...]
>
> - Store a key/value pair into the dictionary unconditionally, 
>     overwriting any value for that key if the key already exists...
>
>   - Use the indexer’s setter, e.g. dictionary[key] = newValue.
>
>     ```
>     public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
>     ```

That will *overwrite* the existing value with the new one - am I right in saying that's what you want, rather than basing the new value *on* the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [AddOrUpdate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675.aspx).